# Оптимально спарсить много сайтов одного типа. Jsoup

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup, localdate

Есть сайт формата
http://www.site.name/YYYY-MM-DD
Мне необходимо спарсить текст со всех страниц этого сайта за текущий год.
Придумал такую систему

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(LocalDate.now().getYear(), i, 1);
        for(int j = 1; j <= date.lengthOfMonth(); j++){
            date = LocalDate.of(2020, i, j);
            Thread.sleep(100);
            services.add(SiteGetter.getSite(URLBody + date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormatter))));
        }
    }
```

Но вместо ожидаемого он в итоге выдает ошибку:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://www.site.name/2020-04-100
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:762)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:297)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:286)
    at WebService.SiteGetter.getSite(SiteGetter.java:10)
    at WebService.SiteContainer.setServices(SiteContainer.java:26)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

При этом вывод того что он кладет в лист services останавливается примерно на 8 июля 2020. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: страница `http://www.site.name/2020-04-100` не существует, потому и не работает. Проверяли ее вручную?

Comment: Да, такой не существует. Но я пытался чтобы оно написало не 2020-04-100 а генерировала корректную дату

Comment: Так если у вас вопрос о том, что код генерирует некорректную дату, то так и пишите, заголовок `оптимально спарсить много сайтов` к проблеме не относится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скоре всего проблема в формате даты. Составляющая формата `DD` - это номер дня в *году*, а вам скорее всего нужен номер дня в *месяце*.

Замените формат на `YYYY-MM-dd`.

Answer (score 0):

Да, вся проблема заключалась в формате даты. В моей ситуации он вообще был не нужен.

Comment: Не нужно писать в виде ответа то, что им не является. Это скорее должен быть комментарий к ответу.